# c# word How do I align my text to the right side?

Tags: c#, ms-word

an example:

[image]

```
Word.Paragraph objPara2;
    objPara2 = objDoc.Paragraphs.Add();


    objPara2.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;


    objPara2.Range.Text = labelLeft.Text;


    objPara2.Range.InsertAfter(labelRight.Text);
```

the two labels must be inserted as in the image.
thanks...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# How To Align Text On Both Left And Right Sides On Same Line Of A Word Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600979/c-sharp-how-to-align-text-on-both-left-and-right-sides-on-same-line-of-a-word-do)

Comment: Please edit your original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600979/c-sharp-how-to-align-text-on-both-left-and-right-sides-on-same-line-of-a-word-do) with this information, rather than starting a new question that's essentially the same. Also, please explain why the suggestion in the comment there does not fulfill your needs. You'll find an [edit] link below the question. Once you've edited it with this information it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, we have found is, create the paragraph manually and also insert  merge fields manually in the document, then you can look them up at generation time thusly. Controlling paragraph widths, alignments etc, is way easier in Word, than in code.

```
var listOfCurrentFields = wordDoc.Fields;

              ..
                foreach (Field myMergeField in listOfCurrentFields)
                {
                    var rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;

                    var fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;
.....


                    if (fieldText.Contains("MERGEFIELD"))
                    {

            if (fieldName.ToLower().Contains("leftlabel"))
                        {
                            myMergeField.Select();
                            wordApp.Selection.TypeText(LeftLabelText);
                        }
....

}
```

Comment: we produce around 200-250K Word docs per year, this is the best way we have found, why write code when you don't need to. The answer from Cindy also completely works. Both methods however, have in common, layout manipulation of the word doc via the application and not code.